# How to add url link from jquery through css element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, href

Here is the code:

```
<span class='maincaptionsmall'>
Test
</span>
```

For some reasons of ajax and jquery codes in my page, I can't use HREF as Link, I mean, I can't use something like this following code:

```
<span class='maincaptionsmall'><a href="http://google.com">Test</a></span>
```

So, How can i use jquery to get this css element `maincaptionsmall` and it will set it to href link ?

Even I can't use `<div>` too, I should use everything as `<span>`
Please give me an example that how to use jquery to set css element as href link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you add styles and yet not edit the HTML? What are you trying to do, inject a link into a page?

Comment: Styling is meant for styling.

Comment: Yes something like inserting URL from JS or CSS file inside of html file, cause I can't use as usual way.

Comment: You can insert a link with JavaScript, but not with CSS.

Answer (score 3):

CSS is not capable of doing such things. But JavaScript is! To change the `href` of an element first obtain the element:

```
var e = document.getElementById("elementid")
```

or

```
var e = document.getElementByClassName("elementclass")
```

[Here are the basics on JavaScript selectors.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

And then we can change the href property like so:

```
e.setAttribute("href", "http://google.com")
```

Good Luck!

Comment: You mean like this code: function example (){var e = document.getElementByClassName("example")e.setAttribute("href", "http://yourdomain.com/")
}  ??  and use id='example'  in html ??  is it possible to give me perfect example ?

Comment: Yeah except your missing a semicolon and some older browsers may not understand `yourdomain.com/` and also if you set the ID you would have to search by the id not the class name with `getElementById` Here is the fixed code: `function example(){var e = document.getElementById("example"); e.setAttribute("href", "http://yourdomain.com")}`

Comment: actually not working, I did it, give me another idea to use it. thnx buddy

Comment: I tried all methods, not working, even like this: var d=new Date(); $("#mylink").attr("href","domain.com" + d.getTime() + "..");  or even like this: var d = ''; var newUrl = oldUrl + d.getTime(); alert(newUrl); window.location = newUrl;

Comment: There are many syntax errors in your code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax

Comment: Why are you setting the attribute of the tag instead of the property of the element?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to get a solution for this problem, the problem is that href doesn't work so i need to use another way,  so, in this case, I'm trying all possibilities ways maybe one of them will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can open using JS/JQuery and CSS

Jquery has short simple code and is too fast too so I prefer that:-

Here is the Code :-

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 //Remember to add JQUERY on your page to make any jquery code work
<div id="example">Click Here</div>
```

**JS**

//UPDATED CODE:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#example").click(function () {
    alert("K");
    window.open('http://www.google.com/');
});
});
```

the Issue was that the function I gave you should be added under "$(document).ready(function(){"

Reg, "DIV or SPAN" u can use any tag, but give ID to that and whatever ID you are giving, mention the same in jQuery code too!

And Reg, JQUERY being called, please check on your page is there any other MAIN Jquery file being called? if there is already some other Jquery being called then this one is not required.

Please Check the updated Fiddle for your reference: **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/aPbje/**

Let me know if this resolves you issue.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thnx for your post, but your code doesn't work! Here is test file, you can check it out. [link]http://www.malayatourism.com/thisistest/test.php  one more thing, that jquery.1.10.1.min.js will effect to my page, and when i put this JS file inside of my page, totally my page wont load. I don't know what is the issue. First we need to solve this  above test file, maybe its cause of this jquery link. I'm waiting for your reply. thnx buddy

Comment: If its possible for you, while you are trying to solve this issue, please don't use <div> , just use <span> if its possible. Thank you soo much

Comment: Updated the code for your issue.. Please see the updated code above